# vTaskDelay never return

Tags: stm32, freertos

My application run on stm32F4 with FreeRTOS V9.0.0 and port files Source\portable\RVDS\ARM_CM4F (imported via RTE Keil).
The main, call some initialization functions, create the task and then call the vTaskStartScheduler.
The task simply call vTaskDelay(1000) which never return. The system is not is fault. The fault report dosen't show any error or problem.

The code is:

```
int main(void) 
{
 init_foo1()
 init_foo2()
 xTaskCreate(aTask, "name",1280, NULL, 6, NULL);
 init_foo3();
 vTaskStartScheduler();
 }
 void aTask()
 {
 vTaskDelay(1000);
 bar();
 }
```

What is wrong?
Thanks all

Comment: unknown functions unknown behaviour - ask the question properly

Comment: Function definition are not NOT relevat for this problem. vTaskDelay funtion is weel defined in FreeRTOS documentation.  Behaviour is mentioned. What is still need?

Comment: if NOT (do not shout at me) look for the solution yourself. Voting to put on hold

Comment: I don't have shout you, but just replay to your comment :)

Comment: Please check your `configTICK_RATE_HZ` macro in `FreeRTOSConfig.h`. After that try this: `vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_RATE_MS);`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put infinite loop firstly:

Example usage of **vTaskDelay** function accordinly to [documentation](http://www.freertos.org/a00127.html):

```
 void vTaskFunction( void * pvParameters )
 {
 /* Block for 500ms. */
 const TickType_t xDelay = 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

     for( ;; )
     {
         /* Simply toggle the LED every 500ms, blocking between each toggle. */
         vToggleLED();
         vTaskDelay( xDelay );
     }
}
```

Also test the priority in **xTaskCreate**

```
UBaseType_t uxPriority
```